# Preparing bootable SSDs for 20 students

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, bootable-media

I teach a class in Robotics and I have 20 students with various windows, mac and the odd linux laptop. They come in all shapes and sizes. So to give the students max chance of success I want to give them each a prepared external SSD with ubuntu and the relevant software on it. And I want it to be bootable.

The approach I am taking is to build a master SSD which has the right software and is bootable and then make duplicates of that one.

1) The process for making the "master" SSD bootable seems to be incredibly gnarly based on my [research so far](https://florisvanbreugel.wordpress.com/2018/03/23/installing-ubuntu-on-an-external-ssd-drive-on-a-macbook/). Has anyone found a way to improve on this process?

2) I can't find a way to duplicate the master such that the dup is also bootable. Has anyone found a way to do this?

#### Some notes

- I plan to do the work on an Ubuntu computer. The resultant SSD should of course be bootable on Mac, Windows and Linux itself
- Giving each student a Pi is a good idea, except that they have to run graphics and cpu intensive programs (it's a robotics course) which I assume will not run well on a Pi
- Would the story be different if I had students boot using a usb stick and then use their laptop's own hard disk for storage? I guess this is the 'try ubuntu' mode? I assume that the performance will be horrible because the OS will use the memory stick for swapping etc.
- Would the story be different if instead of making a bootable memory stick I made a bootable SSD "install medium"?

Comment: How about disk imaging using free software such as Macrium Reflect, and restoring the image to each SSD, which is rapid? BTW, some older machines **cannot** boot from SSD; BIOS does not recognize the device.

Comment: Wouldn't a virtual machine be simpler and easier to create and distribute? Or get all of them to buy something like a Raspberry Pi so that they have a common platform that they are working on?

Comment: @Mokubai good suggrstion, but I suspect this will cause difficulties if they need to interface with Bluetooth/USB passthrough.

Comment: Could you clone an Ubuntu "bootable image" and adding scratch space? Look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/705472/how-to-add-an-extra-writeable-partition-to-a-bootable-usb-stick

Comment: On modern Macs with a T2 chip & SecureBoot, you may need to be aware of this & be able to teach users how to switch it off - https://support.apple.com/HT208330 - though it makes their machines stealable so it's not really advisable. I imagine macOS Catalina will harden this even further.

Comment: As @Tetsujin properly points out, on some Apple products, the SSD cannot even be replaced.  A device being able to support SSD is not guaranteed.  There are Intel chipsets that do not support NVMe, being able to boot from an external SSD, is also not guaranteed to be supported.

Comment: Please see my updated question above. Also (and this could be a separate SO question but I fear the moderators): Can I use Ubuntu's installation process (download iso, 'flash" etc) to create an SSD installer. And then boot off that SSD and use the "try ubuntu" to run and store files on the laptop's own disk? I bet that's not workable but ...)

Comment: @ramhound it would have to be a 12+ year old computer to not support booting form external media. I can guarantee that any Mac can do so. And the ability to do so on PC has been ubiquitous since before the launch of Vista. Secure boot, however, is a problem for booting external media on both platforms.

Comment: @pitosalas - If you have another question, you really should submit a question, questions in a comment are rarely addressed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support both PC and Mac, you will need two masters. I don't think there is any way around that. This is because the way Mac boots is significantly different from PC... even PCs using uefi.

You can get the ISO to make the Ubuntu install media [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

### Making The Masters

#### PC

For the PC master, there's a trick that will make life simpler. First, disable uefi booting on the machine you are using to make the master. Then install using the Ubuntu install media without uefi enabled. This will force the installer to install to the master using MBR booting. This will give you the maximum compatability as all PCs today still support this boot method... while older PCs may not support uefi. Make sure to re-enable uefi before rebooting into your own OS.

On PC you shouldn't need to do anything special. Ubuntu's boot routines are robust enough to detect a change in hardware and adjust accordingly each boot. I personally keep an installation of Ubuntu on a portable 2.5" harddrive that I use for diagnostics on whatever computer I come across. It has never failed to recognize mission critical hardware with the exception of wifi. And, in the case of wifi, support is very good for laptops.

#### Mac

For the Mac I'm less certain. I've worked with Mac a fair bit and even have one here... but I've never tried to put Linux on one. You *will* need a Mac to create the master. The instructions you linked are good. Those instructions are more complicated than PC due to needing an hfs+ boot partition and not using a standard efi partition like you would on a PC. This is Apple's SOP of vendor lock-in at work.

### Making Bootable Disk Mirrors

Now, for mirroring the disks all you really need is a disk imaging/cloning application and a way to hook master and target SSDs up to the same machine. Clonezilla is free for [download](https://www.clonezilla.org/downloads.php) and runs from a cd. If you find Clonezilla to be a bit... temperamental... I would suggest Paragon's Drive Copy. It's not free but I've used it for over a decade in my work as a computer tech, and it's rock solid. Other options include Acronis' line of software. Regardless of what software you use for the job, you want to clone the entire disk from your master SSDs to the destination. This will clone the boot-sector (in the case of the MBR-based PC master) and partition flags as well. Don't worry if you get an warning about having to make a bit-by-bit copy with the hfs+ or hidden partitions, it takes longer to make an image of such partitions... but it will still work when done.

### Gotchas

#### Wifi

The biggest problem you will face on PC is wifi support. Despite what the fanboys will tell you linux still has serious issues with hardware support. As I said before, the wifi adapters commonly found in laptops tend to be well supported... if not at their full capabilities. But, if you run into a laptop that has unsupported wifi hardware, you may find yourself scrambling to find a solution. There may simply not be one. Even using NDISWrapper... which lets you use a windows driver under linux... may not be an option in some cases. Instructions for using NDISWrapper can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper). Being this is a robotics lab, I'm assuming you will have workstations set aside for students. The best solution here is to make sure there is wired ethernet available as each such workstation.

#### Robotics

I'm assuming the robotics hardware will need to interface with the computers as well. Whether conectiong via USB or Serial or twist pair I wouldn't expect a huge issue here. Hardware of this kind sees a disproportionate amount of support on linux. Obviously, you should test it before hand if you are unsure. You can always pre-load the master with any needed kernel modules and software to get it running.

#### Secure Boot

Lastly, you will need to be able to disable secure boot. This is pretty straight forward for most PCs. Have the student enter their bios and disable it. It should be clearly labeled. On Mac, @Tesujin provided [this link](https://support.apple.com/HT208330). It honestly should be even easier on Mac than PC.

### Remaining Questions

#### Using a Memory-Stick With the Ubuntu Live-Environment

Linux doesn't swap as much as Windows. So it's less of an issue. Systems with more than 4GB of ram often don't need swap at all. This is likely owing to it's common role as a server OS. That said, yes, having the swap on a memory stick will be slow. And the live-environment found on the Ubuntu installation media is horribly hobbled. It may not matter... but it probably will.

And... I'm not 100% sure you'd get Mac to boot it.

#### Using an SSD with the Ubuntu Live-Environment

"Would the story be different if instead of making a bootable memory stick I made a bootable SSD "install medium"?"

Yes in regards to swap... no in regard to how hobbled the Ubuntu live-environment is.

Still not 100% on Mac booting it.

### Additional Note Regarding USB/ThunderBolt

Almost all modern PCs support USB3.0 which has a data transfer rate roughly equal to that of SATA3. USB2, however, is terrifyingly slow. A linux environment booting across a USB2 link should still be quite usable but the loading and saving of large files will be a bottleneck. I'm assuming the instructions for controlling robots is fairly simple and doesn't create large files... but you're the expert there.

For your PCs I would get USB3 hard drive enclosures to put your SSDs in. That is, assuming you don't buy them already in a USB3 enclosure. If used on a USB2 connection the USB3 enclosure should gracefully downgrade to USB2. Make sure you get enclosures with the option to provide power from a wall outlet. Most laptops should be able to provide enough power for the SSD just from the USB port itself... but there's a few out there that have trouble with it.

For Mac... well... Apple loves their vendor lock-in. You may or may not have usb ports. You may or may not have thunderbolt. You *should* have one or the other. For this reason the USB3 enclosures used for the PCs should work with Macs that have USB3. You will need different, likely more expensive, enclosures for those using thunderbolt. The good news is that thunderbolt is ridiculously fast. Because of this problem I would suggest getting the SSDs and the enclosures separately and making sure the enclosures are such that you can quickly swap the SSDs between them if needed. You might want to pick up a few enclosures with firewire too... just to be sure.

Comment: This says a whole lot, but actually imparts very little. Your anti-Apple bias shows your knowledge gaps too.

Comment: I'm... having a hard time making sense of your claims. This directly answers the questions asked. Also, I was pretty clear that, in this particular area especially, my Mac knowledge is lacking. I made a point only to share what I was certain of. As for anti-Apple bias... I'm sorry but if you're trying to argue that acknowledging specific, relevant examples of Apple's well documented history of anti-consumer practices is "bias" then I don't think it's me that's biased. In fact, I think there is a great deal to love about Mac OS X in particular and their hardware in general. But not the company.